# How to remove the last row from the text file?

Tags: sql-server, text-files, ssis

What's the easiest way to remove last row from the text file using SQL Server Integration Services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because SSIS is pipeline based, there's no good way to look ahead and know that a line is the last line.

However, depending on your actual goal, there are a number of ways to achieve this:

- If the last row has some identifying
  information, it can simply be
  filtered out using the built-in
  filter component.
- You can create a custom component
  which does buffer the pipeline a
  little and leaves off the last row.
- You can add a row counter, output
  the file to a raw file and then read
  the raw file, excluding the last row
  using a filter

Answer (score 0):

Cade has some excellent answers, but just to add another option, you may wish to preprocess the file in a more generaly language like PowerShell or Python to create a new version omitting the offending last line before bringing it in to SQL.